# How do I declare a public enum in typescript?

Tags: enums, typescript

For the following class:

```
module LayoutEngine {

    enum DocumentFormat {
        DOCX = 1
    };

    export class DocHeader {

        public format : DocumentFormat;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. The above has a compile error where it says "Public property
   'format' of exported class has or is using private type
   'DocumentFormat'." but a declaration of public before the enum is
   also an error. So how do I do this?
2. Is there a way to place the enum declaration inside the class? Just a module name isn't great for namespacing as I have a lot of classes in that module.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> The above has a compile error where it says "Public property 'format' of exported class has or is using private type 'DocumentFormat'.

Simply export :

```
module LayoutEngine {

    export enum DocumentFormat {
        DOCX = 1
    };

    export class DocHeader {

        public format : DocumentFormat;
    }
}
```

> Is there a way to place the enum declaration inside the class?

the `enum` typescript type needs to be at a module level (a file or inside a module). Of course if you want it inside the class just use a json object

```
module LayoutEngine {
    export class DocHeader {
        DocumentFormat = {
            DOCX: 1
        };

        public format : number;
    }
}
```