# How to access an enum in parent class (typescript)

Tags: enums, typescript, webstorm

Our application is built on class, ***not modules*** (making reference to the following question and answer: [How do I declare a public enum in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072208/how-do-i-declare-a-public-enum-in-typescript/23072601#23072601) ).

Here's an example of the code structure:

```
// GrandParent.ts
enum DAYS {SUNDAY,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,FRIDAY, SATURDAY};
class GrandParent {
    // Some super cool stuff
} 
export = GrandParent

//Parent.ts
import GrandParent = require('./GrandParent');
class Parent extends GrandParent {
    // Some things even cooler
}
export = Parent

// Child.ts
import Parent = require('./Parent');
class Child extends Parent {
    getMonday():DAYS{           //Could not find symbol 'DAYS'
        return DAYS.MONDAY; 
    }
}
export = Child
```

When I try to transpile the code I get the following error in webstorm: error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'DAYS'.

Is there a way to access the `enum` in `GrandParent` form `Child` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `export =`, it is a declaration of the *only* thing exported from the file.

If you want to export more than one thing from a module, use multiple `export` declarations:

```
// GrandParent.ts
export enum DAYS {SUNDAY,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,FRIDAY, SATURDAY};
export class GrandParent {
    // Some super cool stuff
} 

//Parent.ts
import GrandParent = require('./GrandParent');
class Parent extends GrandParent.GrandParent {
    // Some things even cooler
}
var x = GrandParent.DAYS.MONDAY;
export = Parent
```

Comment: Webstorm transpiler tells me that there can only one export in the file.

Comment: can't recreate. What is the transpiler output? What typescript version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do

```
module portal{

 enum DAYS {SUNDAY,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,FRIDAY, SATURDAY};


}


module portal.logic{

 //now in this module you can access enum of parent module no need for require

  export class GrandParent {
// Some super cool stuff
} 


 class Parent extends GrandParent.GrandParent {
// Some things even cooler
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is in the context of a module.Since I work with classes I can only use the export once in the file.